# How to add products other badges than "new" and "sale"

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product, badge

I am working on e-commerce website using wordpress, may someone tell me how to add on products other badges than "new" and "sale"

Answer (score 2):

I've found several plugins, free and premium for Woocommerce product badges.

- https://wordpress.org/plugins/yith-woocommerce-badges-management/
- https://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-products-badge-management/6770699
- https://codecanyon.net/item/improved-sale-badges-for-woocommerce/9678382
- https://woocommerce.com/products/woocommerce-advanced-product-labels/

After checking all the options I've made it myself. If you use woocommerce, it adds tags and category-based classes to product box containers. Based on this we can add CSS ::before and ::after to elements. So we can add any badge text as *content* property there. Just add any tag to your product to have some class added and do CSS as needed.

Comment: Would you be able to share your code? Your proposed solution appears very elegant. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I'm not done yet and ideally I would like to move this to a plugin, but here's what I have so far.

Use this code (in functions.php for now) to add a tab to your products indicating, for me, new arrivals and exlusive products. You can change to your liking.

```
 /**
 *
 * This creates a tab on simple and variable products to hold
 * ZhenTea custom settings.
 * 
 * Thanks to http://jeroensormani.com/adding-custom-woocommerce-product-fields/
 * 
 * Relies on customizations to 
 * /zhenteadev/wp-content/themes/jupiter-child/components/shortcodes/mk_products/mk_products.php
 * in order to render badges.
 *
 */
function zt_custom_product_data_tab($tabs)
{
    $tabs['zt_custom_product_settings'] = array(
        'label' => __('ZhenTea', 'woocommerce'),
        'target' => 'zt_custom_product_options',
        'class' => array(
            'show_if_simple',
            'show_if_variable'
        ),
        'priority' => '10'
    );

    return $tabs;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_product_data_tabs', 'zt_custom_product_data_tab');

// add_filter('woocommerce_product_data_panels', 'zt_custom_product_data_tab'); // WC 2.6 and up

/**
 * This is the content of the ZhenTea custom
 * product tab
 *
 * http://jeroensormani.com/adding-custom-woocommerce-product-fields/
 */
function zt_custom_product_tab_contents()
{
    global $post;
    // Note the 'id' attribute needs to match the 'target' parameter set above
    ?><div id='zt_custom_product_options' class='panel woocommerce_options_panel'><?php
    ?><div class='options_group'><?php
    woocommerce_wp_checkbox(array(
        'id' => '_zt_new_arrival',
        'label' => __('Is this a new arrival?', 'woocommerce')
    ));
    woocommerce_wp_checkbox(array(
        'id' => '_zt_zhentea_exclusive',
        'label' => __('Is this a ZhenTea exclusive?', 'woocommerce')
    ));
    ?></div>

    </div><?php
}
add_filter('woocommerce_product_data_panels', 'zt_custom_product_tab_contents');

/**
 * Save the custom fields.
 * http://jeroensormani.com/adding-custom-woocommerce-product-fields/
 */
function zt_save_custom_product_settings($post_id)
{
    $zt_new_arrival = isset($_POST['_zt_new_arrival']) ? true : false;

    update_post_meta($post_id, '_zt_new_arrival', $zt_new_arrival);

    $zt_zhentea_exclusive = isset($_POST['_zt_zhentea_exclusive']) ? true : false;
    update_post_meta($post_id, '_zt_zhentea_exclusive', $zt_zhentea_exclusive);
}
add_action('woocommerce_process_product_meta_simple', 'zt_save_custom_product_settings');
add_action('woocommerce_process_product_meta_variable', 'zt_save_custom_product_settings');
```

I had to modify mk_products.php from my theme in a child theme to catch the new settings.

```
    // Check if product is new arrival and apply badge
    $newArrival = get_post_meta($product_id, '_zt_new_arrival');
    if ($newArrival) {
        $sale_badge = apply_filters('woocommerce_sale_flash', '<span class="onsale"><span>' . __('Sale', 'mk_framework') . '</span></span>', $post, $product);
    }
    // check if product is ZhenTea Exclusive and apply badge

    if ($mk_options['woocommerce_loop_show_desc'] == 'true') {
        $item_desc = apply_filters('woocommerce_short_description', $post->post_excerpt);
    } else {
        $item_desc = '';
    }
```

And I haven't got the css bit done yet.
I realize this is a fairly abominable hack. I'm hoping to move it to a plugin, where it really belongs and replace the css badges with something more custom. I'll update as I progress. I literally stumbled across your post, looking for a solution to my own css update issues in the last phase of this hack.

Comment: what is write_log function?

Comment: Hi. write_log is a custom function I made for logging. I probably should've removed that before posting.

Comment: i have to try your code but it is not working showing error on the write_log ?

Comment: write_log is a custom function I made, hence you are getting an error. Remover references to it and it should work. I removed it from the original as well.